# Clojure promise inside atom map

Tags: multithreading, clojure, promise

I am trying to track requests to a server, and do something when the data is ready. I have the following code which seems to work but I wonder if there's a better way to do it - in particular I find it strange that, in the future below, I'm dereferencing a promise inside dereferencing an atom, with the atom possibly changing state.

```
(def requests (atom {:a (promise) :b (promise)}))
(future @(:b @requests) (println "b is ready"))
(swap! requests assoc :c (promise))
(deliver (:b @requests) 100)
>> b is ready
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Atoms](https://clojure.org/reference/atoms) were designed to solve exactly this problem:

> Internally, swap! reads the current value, applies the function to
>   it, and attempts to compare-and-set! it in. Since another thread may
>   have changed the value in the intervening time, it may have to retry,
>   and does so in a spin loop.

So you are safe here as long as two threads don't use the same key for the map (:a :b :c).

Answer (score 1):

The main issue I see with this approach is that you put this promise inside an atom, but if anyone ever actually mutates the atom to contain a different promise, your program will break: the watcher will be waiting on a promise that nobody else has a reference to. Instead, I'd put the promise inside some immutable structure shared by the two parts of the code that need to communicate.

You could be a bit fancier and use a core.async channel instead of a promise, but if you only ever need to deliver a single value, a promise is fine.

Comment: Thank you, understand concern. But I need some sort of mutable structure as requests will keep coming (unless I create a very very long immutable map to start with?). In my case the map will only grow (new requests added), never change, so hopefully it's fine.

Comment: How will you assign keys in a coordinated way to all requests the server will ever receive? You have at least two threads working on this map and they all have to somehow agree on what key corresponds to what request. And if the map never shrinks, then it grows without bound as more requests come in and you run out of memory.

Comment: I have one main scheduler that sends requests periodically, with keys being atomic numbers going up sequentially: only one thread adds to the map. Other threads deliver promises from the map. My issue is more that some requests take longer to run than others and I need to have some sort of wait / callback when data is ready. On the memory issue - that should be manageable, with a few ~1000 requests before each program restart.